# Moving submodules with Git

Tags: git, move, git-submodules

Is there any way to move submodules within your superproject without removing them first and re-adding them ?

Comment: This was asked in 2010. The question you linked is from 2011

Comment: Sure, but the other question is also much more “popular” (e.g. it has over three times the views; it and its answers have garnered many more votes–even the accepted, identical answer). Anyway, it does not matter much since any close votes expired long ago.

Comment: This question was also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/how-do-i-move-an-existing-git-submodule-within-a-git-repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's similar to how you removing a submodule (see [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)):

- Edit .gitmodules and change the path of the submodule appropriately, and put it in the index with `git add .gitmodules`
- If needed, create the parent directory of the new location of the submodule: `mkdir -p new/parent`
- Move all content from the old to the new directory: `mv -vi old/parent/submodule new/parent/submodule`
- Remove the old directory with `git rm --cached old/parent/submodule`

Looks like this for me afterwards:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   .gitmodules
#       renamed:    old/parent/submodule -> new/parent/submodule
#
```

- Finally commit the changes.

Comment: Wish there was a Git command that could all of that for you ;)

Comment: These instructions don't work.

Comment: Didn't work for me either; `new/parent/submodule` showed up as an untracked file, `old/parent/submodule` as deleted. I ended up removing & readding the submodule

Comment: You need to git add the new submodule directory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is for now.

There is a [patch in the making](http://lists-archives.org/git/715709-implement-git-mv-for-submodules.html) for a teaching "**[`git mv`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html)**" how to handle moving submodules, including how to update the `.gitmodules` file.
But it is not there yet.
Simply [switching a remote repo for an existing submodule is simpler](http://mylescarrick.com/articles/moving_a_git_submodule), but not what you want.