# How to move Git submodule to sub-directory?

Tags: git, git-submodules

guys, I just used submodule to organize some Git repos, here's the address:
[repos](https://github.com/shawjia/repos)

I want to move all the submodule into a new directory called repos, for examples, jquery -> repos/jquery.

I change the **.gitmodules** file, but seems it doesn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: See "[How do I move an existing git submodule within a git repository?][1]"


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/how-do-i-move-an-existing-git-submodule-within-a-git-repository

Answer (score 43):

Since git 1.8.5,

```
git mv old/submod new/submod
```

works as expected and does all the plumbing for you. You might want to use git 1.9.3 or newer, because it includes fixes for submodule moving.

Credits: Mike Lowerey from comment below

#### Original answer

Had the same problem just the moment ago and ended up deleting the submodule reference  (as outlined [in this article](http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)) and recreating it where i wanted it to go.

To follow your example of moving submodule `jquery` into `repos/jquery`

1. Delete the (typically three lines) submodule reference from `.gitmodules`.
2. Check `.git/config` for references to the submodule and remove them, if existent
3. do `git rm --cached jquery` to cut the submodule reference out of the repository
4. remove the old submodule folder
5. recreate you submodule reference (as you possibly did before) with `git submodule add git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git repos/jquery`

In case your submodule was [set to specific tag, respectively commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag#1778247) (which you'll surely have in a stable project) you will have set it again.

Due to this complex process i am strongly hoping there is (or will be, at least on the git roadmap) a more straightforward way of achieving this. If not, surely some scripts could be fumbled together to do this quicker...

Comment: Since git 1.8.5, `git mv old/submod new/submod` works as expected and does all the plumbing for you. You might want to use git 1.9.3 or newer, because it includes fixes for submodule moving. [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/how-do-i-move-an-existing-git-submodule-within-a-git-repository).