# Unable to update submodule in github due to exist directory

Tags: git, vim, github, macvim

I am using submodule to control my plugin in MacVim.
When I tried to update the submodule using `git update submodule`
It comes out:

```
fatal: destination path 'bundle/ShowMark' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Clone of 'git://github.com/vim-scripts/ShowMarks.git' into submodule path 'bundle/ShowMark' failed
```

I tried my own solution:
remove the directory and then `git update submodule`
It works but the MacVim cannot run properly. MacVim cannot open any new/old files.

Comment: Your problem is very unclear. Can you give us more information on what exactly is and is not working?

Comment: I have a submodule in 'bundle/ShowMark', and I cannot update it by `git submodule update` because it already exist orz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'si possible MacVim has issue opening files in `bundle/ShowMark` because the actual repo name on GitHub is `ShowMark**s**(.git)`.

It might be better if that submodule was register to be in `bundle/ShowMarks`.
See "[How do I move an existing git submodule within a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/how-do-i-move-an-existing-git-submodule-within-a-git-repository)" for more on that step.

Answer (score 1):

a general solution worked for me

```
git submodule deinit --force . 
git submodule init 
git submodule update --recursive
```