# After moving git submodule to another directory it fails with error 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Initially I had the following (simplified) repo structure:

```
MyRepo
   external1/MySub (git submodule)
   .gitsubmodules
```

Where

```
$ cat .gitsubmodules

  [submodule "external1/MySub"]
  path = external1/MySub
  url = user@repo:/remoterepo/externals/MySub.git
```

I then wanted to move MySubmodule to another directory in the same git repository, e.g., *external2* so the structure is as follows:

```
MyRepo
   external2/MySub (git submodule)
   .gitsubmodules
```

---

What I did, and thought is enough, I simply moved (via OS `mv`) the *external1/MySub* directory to *external2/MySub* and edited the *.gitsubmodules* file to:

```
$ cat .gitsubmodules

  [submodule "external2/MySub"]
  path = external2/MySub
  url = user@repo:/remoterepo/externals/MySub.git
```

After this change, I get the following error:

```
$ git status

  fatal: Could not chdir to '../../../../../repo/external/MySub': No such file or directory
  fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule repo/external2/MySub
```

---

What am I missing? Any other changes need to be done for such move to work?

(I'm using git version 1.8.3rc3 on Windows 8.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move an existing Git submodule within a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/how-do-i-move-an-existing-git-submodule-within-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> I simply moved the external1/MySub directory to external2/MySub

Move as in `mv` (unix command), or `git mv` (git command)?

You need to move the [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) of [the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309) representing the submodule for the parent repo.

Normally, (reading [`git mv`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)), this should have been enough:

```
git mv external1/MySub external2/MySub
```

> Moving a submodule using a gitfile (which means they were cloned with a Git version 1.7.8 or newer) will update the `gitfile` and `core.worktree` setting to make the submodule work in the new location.
>   It also will attempt to update the `submodule.<name>.path` setting in the `gitmodules` file and stage that file (unless -n is used).

That works best with the latest 1.8.5 git (like [msysgit for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount), or [latest package for Unix](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa))

---

[Suseika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542343/suseika) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991138/moving-git-submodule-to-another-directory-within-the-same-repository/20991180?noredirect=1#comment58305715_20991180)

> If you get message

```
fatal: renaming '%submodule%' failed: No such file or directory
```

> it is probably because you're adding a directory level, e.g. moving submodule "`math`" to "`libs/math`".
>   `git mv` doesn't create missing [intermediate] directories, you should `mkdir` them yourself.

---

git 2.9 (June 2016) will improve `git mv` for submodule:

See [commit a127331](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a127331cd812336235cb95b45b7e4c52c433be7f) (19 Apr 2016) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9cb50a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cb50a3ca60a5c5969deb83d11782da26c3bcdb7), 29 Apr 2016)</sup>

> ### `mv`: allow moving nested submodules
>
> "`git mv old new`" did not adjust the path for a submodule that lives as a subdirectory inside `old/` directory correctly.
>
> submodules however need to update their link to the git directory as
>   well as updates to the `.gitmodules` file.

---

Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) offers to move nested submodules to the parent repo:

There is a new submodule helper "**`git submodule absorbgitdirs`**" to make it easier to move embedded `.git/` directory for submodules in a
superproject to `.git/modules/` (and point the latter with the former
that is turned into a "`gitdir:`" file) has been added.

See [commit 7c4be45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c4be458b1c7ba81b0cc63d76a144261eb2395be) (27 Dec 2016), [commit f6f8586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f858614003a3da794385cefdbddf00b85f7501), [commit 47e83eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47e83eb3b7d5410769d7f4d3930ba7fa12915680), [commit 1a248cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a248cf21d450eb911d01a89c84412c2da365e66) (12 Dec 2016), and [commit 6f94351](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f94351b0a4dd107623a35dc9081bf31c7ddac88), [commit 89c8626](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89c8626557621ef000930da3c8a23fa03ad7e01a), [commit 90c0011](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90c0011619bd4cd4b14c366ab7a9affacb43276a), [commit 6f94351](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f94351b0a4dd107623a35dc9081bf31c7ddac88), [commit 89c8626](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89c8626557621ef000930da3c8a23fa03ad7e01a), [commit 90c0011](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90c0011619bd4cd4b14c366ab7a9affacb43276a) (08 Dec 2016) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit da2b74e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da2b74eeec0b12d7b20d34a5e284295f81ad40a8), 10 Jan 2017)</sup>

> ### submodule: add `absorb-git-dir` function
>
> When a submodule has its `git` dir inside the working dir, the submodule
>   support for checkout that we plan to add in a later patch will fail.
>
> Add functionality to migrate the git directory to be absorbed
>   into the superprojects git directory.
>
> The newly added code in this patch is structured such that other areas of
>   Git can also make use of it. The code in the submodule--helper is a mere
>   wrapper and option parser for the [function `absorb_git_dir_into_superproject`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/da2b74eeec0b12d7b20d34a5e284295f81ad40a8/submodule.c#L1361-L1369), that takes care of embedding the
>   submodules git directory into the superprojects git dir. That function
>   makes use of the [more abstract function for this use case
>   `relocate_gitdir`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/da2b74eeec0b12d7b20d34a5e284295f81ad40a8/dir.c#L2777-L2780), which can be used by e.g. the worktree code eventually
>   to move around a git directory.

---

Note: there is still (Git 2.14.x/2.15, Q4 2017) a bug linked to submodule moving: see "[Git: moving submodules recursively (nested submodules)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32924692/6309)".

---

Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018) will make moving submodule more robust, since "`git fetch --recurse-submodules`" now **knows that submodules can be
moved around in the superproject in addition to getting updated**,
and finds the ones that need to be fetched accordingly.

See [commit 4b4aced](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b4acedd61c4a6108dc0931e1677b286683e4dbd), [commit c68f837](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c68f8375760dc6b77f9c68772230a9c6cfd52aa7) (16 Oct 2017), and [commit 01ce122](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01ce12252c959ed0f4b4b021adffa7a84a2d64a6) (06 Oct 2017) by [Heiko Voigt (`hvoigt`)](https://github.com/hvoigt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b4d658b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4d658b501a37d14a8542b98b59817ed59977388), 06 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### implement fetching of moved submodules
>
> We store the changed submodules paths to calculate which submodule needs
>   fetching. This does not work for moved submodules since their paths do
>   not stay the same in case of a moved submodules.
>   In case of new submodules we do not have a path in the current checkout, since they just appeared in this fetch.
>
> It is more general to collect the submodule names for changes instead of
>   their paths to include the above cases. If we do not have a
>   configuration for a gitlink we rely on constructing a default name from
>   the path if a git repository can be found at its path. We skip
>   non-configured gitlinks whose default name collides with a configured
>   one.

---

Note that, *before* Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), the code to try seeing if a fetch is necessary in a submodule during a fetch with `--recurse-submodules` got confused when the path to the submodule was changed in the range of commits in the
superproject, sometimes showing "`(null)`".
This has been corrected.

See [commit c3749f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3749f6e597a7b8140181fa5efc95f3f08595f8c), [commit 5fc8475](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fc84755f1478ea8c0f05b8d7be67a3c96a24bff) (14 Jun 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 085d2ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/085d2abf57be3e424cad0b7dc8c27fe41921258e), 28 Jun 2018)</sup>

> ### `submodule`: fix `NULL` correctness in renamed broken submodules
>
> When fetching with recursing into submodules, the fetch logic inspects
>   the superproject which submodules actually need to be fetched.
>   This is tricky for submodules that were renamed in the fetched range of commits.
>   This was implemented in [c68f837](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c68f8375760dc6b77f9c68772230a9c6cfd52aa7) (implement fetching of moved
>   submodules, 2017-10-16, Git v2.16.0), and this patch fixes a mistake in the logic
>   there.

Comment: Reverted all my changes and trying to git mv I'm getting:
$ git mv external/MySub external2/MySub
fatal: source directory is empty, source=external/MySub, destination=external/MySub (even though the source dir is not empty at all)

Comment: @jaccus You need to reset your repo as it was before your `mv`. Then do the `git mv` (without modifying the `.gitmodules`) and see if it works.

Comment: I think that's what I'm running into while doing `git mv` on a submodule http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/VCS/How%20to%20move%20a%20git%20submodule.html

Comment: @jaccus only if you have an old git. Make sure to update to the latest one first (https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa + https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html), then reset, then `git mv`, and it will work.

Comment: I'll check that later on the latest git version (although mine's not that old /added to the question description/). I managed to make it work with the hacks I posted in another answer. I hope it's not too dangerous and won't break something.

Comment: @jaccus git1.8.3rc3 is old (May 2013!) I would advise unzipping an 1.8.5.2 (https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) and test with that (you can keep both git version installed at the same time)

Comment: So `git mv` on a submodule worked like a charm with git 1.8.5.2. Should have updated git in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: @jaccus great! I have edited the answer to reflet that git version pre-requisite.

Comment: I had a folder containing 2 submodules and moved that folder one level deeper using `git mv myfolder/ subfolder/` and I had to correct `gitdir` and `worktree`entries for these folders manually under cygwin git 2.1.1. Tortoise git in Windows Explorer does not show the submodules' status.

Comment: @Bardware I prefer cloning again the parent repo, and use `git mv myfolder` (no trailing `/`): you want to move the **gitlink entry** (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309), not the folder.

Comment: If you get message "fatal: renaming '%submodule%' failed: No such file or directory", it is probably because you're adding a directory level, e.g. moving submodule "math" to "libs/math". `git mv` doesn't create missing directories, you should `mkdir` them yourself.

Comment: @Suseika Good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 18):

I changed a few more things manually and it actually worked with git 1.8.3rc3 (unnecessary with git 1.8.5):

1. Fix `gitdir` path in .git submodule **file** `repo/external2/MySub/.git`:

   ```
   -gitdir: ../../../.git/modules/external1/MySub
   +gitdir: ../../../.git/modules/external2/MySub
   ```
2. Rename submodule directory under `repo/.git/modules/` directory

   ```
   $ mv repo/.git/modules/external1 repo/.git/modules/external2
   ```
3. Fix `worktree` path in `repo/.git/modules/external2/MySub/config`

   ```
   -worktree = ../../../../../external1/MySub
   +worktree = ../../../../../external2/MySub
   ```