# `--name` option doesn't work with `git submodule add` command

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to add a git submodule with different name like:

```
git submodule add --name foo git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/cookbook-foo.git
```

I wanted to create a git submodule directory named `foo`, but the repository are created with the name `cookbook-foo`.

Most likely I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what was wrong.

How can I change the name of git submodule directory?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Don't conflate the *path* and the *name* of a submodule. You want to run

```
git submodule add git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/cookbook-foo.git foo/
```

instead. For more details, see the `git-submodule` man page; the relevant `git-submodule` syntax here is

```
git submodule [--name <name>] <repository> [<path>]
```

where...

- `<repository>` is the URL of the new submodule's origin repository.
- `<path>`, if specified, determines the name of the subdirectory (of the superproject's root directory) to receive the clone of the repo living at `<repository>`; if left unspecified, `<path>` defaults to the name of that repo.
- `<name>` is the submodule's *name*, i.e. the name that appear in the corresponding submodule entry in the `.gitmodules` file; if left unspecified, `<name>` simply defaults to `<path>`.

Here is a toy example to fix ideas:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init
$ git submodule add --name brutus https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute bradfitz_bruteforce
$ ls -a
.           .git            bradfitz_bruteforce
..          .gitmodules
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "brutus"]
    path = bradfitz_bruteforce
    url = https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute
```

Comment: Me, I "conflated" :)

Answer (score 1):

In last versions of git (since 1.8.5) you can do a *git mv* as a second step if the command failed or you forgot to set the option.
The *.submodule* file will automatically updated.

```
git mv cookbook-foo foo
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310246/22503434) for more information about *git mv* over submodules.

Answer (score 0):

In my case at least the answer by @jubObs did not work. I had to add the `--` separator before the URL and the path, as shown in the examples of the `submodule` command's help.

```
$ git submodule -h
usage: git submodule [--quiet] [--cached]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
```

So, for example:

```
git submodule add --name foo \
  -- git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/cookbook-foo.git \
  path/to/foo
```

For reference, my version of Git is 2.30.

```
$ git version
git version 2.30.0
```