# Installing Git version above 1.8.5 on Centos

Tags: linux, git, centos

Earlier today, I ran into problems moving git folders ([Move Git folder containing submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947802/move-git-folder-containing-submodules)), and the recommendation was to use a newer git version above 1.8.5.  Easy, I thought, but haven't been so lucky.

I've searched high and low, and the most recent version I could find in a yum repository is 1.8.3 (PUIAS_6_computational: puias.math.ias.edu).

I then looked for help installing by source (http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-the-latest-git-version-on-centos and http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/ which are almost identical), however, git is only available to the root user, and it is my understanding both these tutorials shouldn't be installing in /usr/local/.

```
# cd git-2.0.4
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
# echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc
# source /etc/bashrc
```

Please provide a means to use Git version greater than 1.8.5.

Comment: 1. There is nothing wrong with installing to `/usr/local` (in fact, that's what the directory is *for*). 2. What do you mean that "git is only available to the root user"? Is `git` not in your user's `$PATH`? If you run `/user/local/git/bin/git` as your user, does it not work?

Comment: @Chris  My bad.  After rebooting, non-root users could use it.  As for why it shouldn't be installed the way I did so, I based it on http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/access-program-installed-by-root-from-source-by-a-regular-user-4175525494/.  Still couldn't find a more recent YUM version.  Is it possible to use git itself to update git?

Comment: `/usr/local/git/bin` isn't in the system path by default, but you added it when you modified `/etc/bashrc`. Rebooting ensured that all users would have re-read that file, seeing the new settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try following this set of instructions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7

Then, do this:

```
yum remove git
exit
# reopen an terminal
```

Comment: This provides general installation instructions for git on centos 7, but is references the default packages, which means git 1.8.3.1, which does NOT answer the question, which explicitly asks for git above 1.8.5

Answer (score -1):

Using Docker you have two options:
If you don't want to install dependencies on your host you could build it with docker, you could try this: https://github.com/wood1986/docker-library/tree/master/git

Or a quick but far from ideal way, you could execute it on a docker container, so every time you run git a container is created, your command is executed and the container is automatically removed and a cleaned up is made.

First: `sudo yum remove git`

then:  `sudo vim /bin/git`
with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -ti --rm -v ${HOME}:/root -v $(pwd):/git alpine/git $@
```

last: `sudo chmod 775 /bin/git`
and add  .gitconfig with your name and email to your home

Check your version: `git --version`