# Using n github repositories for a single github-page website?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'am coding a website which stands on 2 github repositories : WEBSITE.git (2MB or 2%) & AUDIO.git (98MB = 98%). I deploy it as follow :

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/WEBSITE.git
mkdir -p ./audio ./audio/cmn;
git clone https://github.com/<user>/AUDIO.git ./audio/
```

After deploiement the structure is then such as :

```
|- /html/<files>
|- /css/<files>
|- /js/<files>
|- /audio/<AUDIO.git's files>
```

Repository AUDIO is 98% of the project weight (100MB) from a dynamic open sourve project, WEBSITE is my 2% of codes.

Naturally, when I add a `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` to WEBSITE.git, the gh-pages `http(s)://<user>.github.io/WEBSITE/` website works but doesn't have the audios. All as we can expect.

I need the audios to works, the easy way would be to integrate fully these audios to WEBSITE.git. But I'am quite reluctant to add such **heavy files** to its git's history since it will dramatically increase the weight of my html/css/js repository by a factor 50. It matters since I'am teaming up with a dev who have very low internet connection.

**How should I process ? Is there some secret hack to integrate an external github repository to a gh-pages files structures?** (plug AUDIO.git to http(s)://.github.io/MYSITE/audio/ )

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for git submodules.

Comment: According to [Using submodules with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-submodules-with-pages/) : "If your repository contains [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), they will automatically be pulled in when the Page is built."

Comment: @Hugolpz, it doesn't look like you've configured your audio repository as a submodule yet.

Comment: I haven't yet. I'am looking for that as well. (reading docs online)

Comment: @Chris: the answer is `git submodule add -- "https ://github.com/<user>/AUDIO.git " "./audio/" . If you want to add this as an answer I will be happyt to validate it :)

Comment: @Hugolpz, you did most of the work on this one. Why not [add the answer yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: I was not aware self-answering was encourage and well received... Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Github page

Since 2017, user [Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) from github's settings.

### Git submodules

```
# Get project
git clone "https://github.com/<user>/WEBSITE.git"  # clone your project
cd ./WEBSITE/                                      # move in
## Add submodule to target folder
git submodule add -- "https://github.com/<user>/AUDIO.git" "./audio/" 
## Commit changes 
git commit -am "dev,git: add submodule https://github.com/<user>/AUDIO.git" 
git push
## Update/Install submodules locally
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

### Cloning and updating repository

**Cloning the repository *with* submodules for git 1.6.5+ :**

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
```

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/ for add & remove submodules.

Comment: `git config --get remote.origin.url` may also help you to identify the submodule's url.

Comment: To syn the local and remote, you could also do `git push --mirror` or more aggressive ways, see [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437928/1974961)

Answer (score 1):

With Github pages, you can simply do :

#### Main website

Hosted on `github.com/userName/username.github.io`. Eventually with a [custom domain name](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).

Is reached with `username.github.io` or cutom domaine name.

#### Audio files

Hosted on `github.com/userName/audio`.

Is reached with `username.github.io/audio`

#### Local development

The main site can `.gitignore` audio folder which itself host the audio repository. 
This will replicate online folder hierachy.

Comment: Does this need to make a git branch gh-pages for Audio ?

Comment: Yes `master` on userName.github.io an `gh-pages` on other repositories.