# How to avoid duplicate GIT submodule content after moving to another folder? warning: unable to rmdir 'xxx': Directory not empty

Tags: git, git-submodules

#### Initial Situation / Goal

I have a GIT repository with a submodule let's say under `<root>/Modules/SomePath/Example`.

I want to move this submodule to a new location, let's say `<root>/LocalStuff/NewName`.

#### What I did

I basically followed [How do I move an existing Git submodule within a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/how-do-i-move-an-existing-git-submodule-within-a-git-repository) and

- created folder `<root>/LocalStuff/NewName`
- used `git mv /Modules/SomePath/Example/* /LocalStuff/NewName/`
- in `.gitmodules` changed from

  ```
  [submodule "Modules/SomePath/Example"]
      path = Modules/SomePath/Example
      url = xxxxxxxxx
  ```

  to

  ```
  [submodule "LocalStuff/NewName"]
      path = LocalStuff/NewName
      url = xxxxxxxxx
  ```
- in the now `LocalStuff/NewName/.git` changed from

  ```
  gitdir: ../../.git/modules/Modules/SomePath/Example
  ```

  to

  ```
  gitdir: ../../.git/modules/LocalStuff/NewName
  ```
- created according folder `<root>/.git/modules/LocalStuff/NewName`
- moved all content from `<root>/.git/modules/Modules/SomePath/Example` into `<root>/.git/modules/LocalStuff/NewName`
- in the now `<root>/.get/modules/LocalStuff/NewName/config`

changed from

```
worktree = ../../../../Modules/SomePath/Example
```

to

```
worktree = ../../../../LocalStuff/NewName
```

#### Issue / Question

At first glance this worked fine and when I clone my branch everything is fine.

However, when switching between the "main" branch and my "MoveSubmodule" branch forth and back I get a warning

```
warning: unable to rmdir 'LocalStuff/NewName': Directory not empty
```

or accordingly

```
warning: unable to rmdir 'Modules/SomePath/Example': Directory not empty
```

with the result that the submodule is only there once but its content is there twice in the two locations. They are not tracked in GIT as changes though so even if I again delete them manually this is not a change I can commit.

**Have I missed / screwed up anything?**

Comment: The best way to avoid redundancy with git submodules is the same as the solution for nearly all problems with submodules.  Namely, stop using submodules!  They are a kludge on a hack on a bandaid over a scab.  Use proper dependency management and deployment tools!

Comment: You haven't really missed anything. Submodules have a lot of "user experience" issues and this is one of them. Some call them *sob*-modules; this is part of why.