# How to tell git that I already changed the path of a submodule?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-submodules

I have a submodule at the following path: `src/level_1/level_2/my_Submodule`.

In VS Code, I changed the path to: `src/level_1/level_2/level_3/my_Submodule`.

In this case, git gives me an error that the "path to the my_Submodule is not found".

How can I make git to use the new path that I already modified?

I can't use `git mv old_path new_path` because I have to change the path from inside vscode itself, so vscode can update the imports, so I won't have broken paths.

I already read all the similar questions in stackoverflow and none of them solves the situation I explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options (I think):

1. Since you want to do the move in VS Code to use it's auto-update-import-path feature, just do the move with VS Code to use that feature, then undo the move *outside of VS Code* (ex. with the `mv` unix command), and then take the normal route of doing things stated in the answers to [How do I move an existing Git submodule within a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4604486/11107541) (`git mv old/submod new/submod`).
2. Go and update the git files yourself, replacing the previous path with the new path: The repo's `.submodules` file, `.git/config` file, and several others you can find by `cd`ing into the `.git` folder and doing a file-content search (with a tool like grep) for the previous path, such as `.git/modules/<previous path>/config`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 1st option is a clever workaround. the 2nd option won't work, I tried it already. So, isn't there any direct way I could use?

Comment: @AhmedEid I can't think of anything better than what I already wrote. I'd personally wager that no significantly better option exists.